# Why do boosting overfit on the data with uniform noise?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, overfitting, ensemble-learning

i read about it but i didn't get the idea, and actually i didn't find many pages that talk about uniform noise with boosting, is it rare to happen or what?
**another question:**
i read **in some pages** that boosting overfit with large number of weak learners
because it will get the train error to 0 because it trusted the data too much and be confidence and as a consequence it captured the noise
and **in other pages** they say that in ONLY boosting as you increase the number of learners and be more confident you will increase the margin due to margin theory. 
which is correct?

Comment: Please add links and references to your "some pages" and "other pages" so other know precisely what you are refering to.